# Intersection of lists with different size

Tags: java, list, collections, set, intersection

I have this task on interview. I thought it's simple, but...

I have two lists:

```java
List<String> l1 = List.of("A", "B", "A", "A");
List<String> l2 = List.of("A", "C", "A");
```

I need to find what is in common in these two lists.

Of course, I tried this solution:

```java
List<String> l1 = List.of("A", "B", "A", "A");
List<String> l2 = List.of("A", "C", "A");
Set<String> l3 = new HashSet<>(l1);
l3.retainAll(l2);
System.out.println(l3); // outputs A
```

And this:

```java
List<String> l1 = List.of("A", "B", "A", "A");
List<String> l2 = List.of("A", "C", "A");
List<String> l3 = new ArrayList<>(l1);
l3.retainAll(l2);
System.out.println(l3); // outputs A, A, A
```

But I need in output only `A, A`

What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I am missing something, but I think this is enough:

```
List<String> tmp = new ArrayList<>(l2);
List<String> result = l1.stream().filter(tmp::remove).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Running code:

```
public static void main(String []args){
    List<String> l1 = List.of("A", "B", "A", "A");
    List<String> l2 = List.of("A", "C", "A");
    List<String> tmp = new ArrayList<>(l2);
    List<String> result = l1.stream().filter(tmp::remove).collect(Collectors.toList());
    System.out.println(result);
}
```

**Output:**

```
[A, A]
```

Or based on [Holger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2711488/holger) feedback:

> That’s probably the simplest, though not the most efficient for larger
> lists due to the repeated linear searches. Further, stateful
> predicates are discouraged for Stream operations; you could avoid them
> by using:

```
List<String> result = new ArrayList<>(l1); 
result.removeIf(e-> !tmp.remove(e));
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that it is needed to calculate the "frequencies" of each element first in the input lists and then rebuild the list containing elements with less frequency, for example:

```java
Map<String, Integer> map1 = l1.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(x -> x, Collectors.summingInt(x -> 1)));
Map<String, Integer> map2 = l2.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(x -> x, Collectors.summingInt(x -> 1)));

List<String> intersection = map1.entrySet().stream()
        .filter(e -> map2.containsKey(e.getKey())) // filter out missing keys
        .flatMap(e -> Collections.nCopies(
            Math.min(e.getValue(), map2.get(e.getKey())), e.getKey()
            ).stream()
        )
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

System.out.println(intersection);
```

Simpler solution could be to use plain `groupingBy` to get sublists immediately and compare sizes of the sublists to select a shorter one:

```java
Map<String, List<String>> map1 = l1.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(x -> x));
Map<String, List<String>> map2 = l2.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(x -> x));

List<String> intersection2 = map1.entrySet().stream()
        .flatMap(e ->
            (e.getValue().size() < map2.computeIfAbsent(
                e.getKey(), (k) -> Collections.emptyList()                    
            ).size() ? e.getValue() : map2.get(e.getKey())
        ).stream())
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Using `Stream.filter` will not require modifying `map2` with `compute/computeIfAbsent`:

```java
List<String> intersection3 = map1.entrySet().stream()
        .filter(e -> map2.containsKey(e.getKey()))
        .flatMap(e ->
                (e.getValue().size() < map2.get(e.getKey()).size() 
                    ? e.getValue() : map2.get(e.getKey()))
                .stream()
        )
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Change `map2.get(e.getKey())` to `map2.getOrDefault(e.getKey(), 0)` and you don’t need the `filter` step. Use a single step, `.flatMap(e -> Collections.nCopies(Math.min(e.getValue(), map2.getOrDefault(e.getKey(), 0)), e.getKey()).stream())` instead of `map(…).flatMap(…)` and you don’t need to construct temporary `Map.Entry` instances. You could even fuse it to a single collect operation, `List<String> intersection = map1.entrySet().stream() .collect(ArrayList::new, (e,l) -> l.addAll(Collections.nCopies(Math.min(e.getValue(), map2.getOrDefault(e.getKey(), 0)), e.getKey())), List::addAll);`

Comment: @Holger I've come up with another solution

Comment: Removing `Collectors.summingInt(x -> 1)` means now collecting into `List`s (allocating and filling memory), just for the sake of calling `size()` on the result, then, `compute(…, (k, v) -> null == v ? Collections.emptyList() : v)`, which is an unnecessarily complicated alternative to `computeIfAbsent(…, k -> Collections.emptyList())`, means modifying the map despite never using the modified entry (contrary to `getOrDefault`) and you replaced a simple `min` with a manually written conditional expression. In my eyes, none of those changes is an improvement of your first variant.

Comment: allocating and filling memory for sublists is needed anyway (it used to be `Collections.nCopies`), and the sublist with min size is needed to populate the result.

Comment: `Collections.nCopies` does *not* allocate memory for every element. It creates a specialized list holding the single element and the count. `nCopies(1, …)` takes the same amount of memory as `nCopies(1000, …)`. Besides that, your first approach creates them temporarily during the Stream processing, creating and using one at a time, allowing garbage collection of all previously used, in contrast to the map created by `groupingBy` that references all of them, requiring them all to exist at the same time.

Comment: @Holger, I updated initial version to remove redundant `map` step by your first comment, however, I kept `filter` step as it's imho more readable than using `getOrDefault`.  Tried fusing into single collect operation - it did not work, will play with it later.  Thanks for valuable comments, especially about `Collections.nCopies`!

Comment: You think, `getOrDefault` is hard to read or understand? Interesting. Here’s how a single collect op looks like: https://ideone.com/aXromd

Answer (score 0):

Both of your solutions are almost correct, except that in the first solution you use [`Set#retainAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#retainAll(java.util.Collection)) instead of [`List#retainAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#retainAll(java.util.Collection)), and in the second solution, that is already closer, you use it in the opposite direction. Your code should be:

```java
List<String> l1 = List.of("A", "B", "A", "A");
List<String> l2 = List.of("A", "C", "A");
List<String> l4 = new ArrayList<>(l2);
l4.retainAll(l1);
System.out.println(l4); // [A, A]
```